# How to pass RecordId from a record detail page into a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a Case record detail page with a custom object on the related list section.
I've overwritten the "New" quickaction of that custom object to a custom Visualforce page.

Here what I want to do is to press "New" - on this custom object which has a lookup to the Case - from a Related List on the Case object.
When I press on the "New" of the custom object, I will navigate to that page - **then I wont be in the Case Record page anymore**.

The goal is to get the new record of the custom object to be related to that Case that stated the process.
That's I need to get the Case RecordId on its controller.
I've tried this on the page:

```
console.log(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
```

and this on the controller (extension):

```
public TFB_TM_TMChecklistNewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        system.debug('URL ID: ' + controller.getId());
...
```

None of this worked.

The visualforce page has its controller and an extension:

```
apex:page standardController="TFB_TM_Checklist__c" extensions="TFB_TM_TMChecklistNewController"
```

Can someone advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get that in vf page-

```
    <apex:page standardController="TFB_TM_Checklist__c" 
    extensions="TFB_TM_TMChecklistNewController">

    TFB_TM_Checklist Record Id is {!TFB_TM_Checklist__c.Id}

    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wont be on the Case detail page anymore, since I would be brought to that visualforce page URL. So this would not work. Also, I need the ID of the existing Case, not the ID of the TFB_TM_Checklist__c that does not exist yet